# Do you need to add an index on a partitioned table (postgres 11)?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

My team is looking at moving our non partitioned table with ~1TB of data over to a partitioned table.

We would be using range partitioning based on a timestamp column.

One thing I don't understand is whether we need to add an index on the timestamp column if it's being used as the partition key. If we make our partitions quite small (e.g. partition for every day), would this act in a similar way to an index?

We would only be doing queries on a maximum resolution of one day.

I am reluctant to add an index as we've tried this in the past and it never completed (probably because we didn't turn off writes. Not really an option to turn off writes for an extended period).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your feeling is right: omitting the index on the partitioning column is one of the few places where partitioning actually makes queries faster.

You can then get away with a sequential scan of a single partition, and you don't have to maintain the index with every data modifying statement.

The other advantage is that partitioning makes mass deletion of data (along the partition boundaries) so much more efficient. And finally, autovacuum's job will become easier.

Two points about partitioning:

- Upgrade to v12; there have been substantial performance improvements that concern partitioning.
- Don't use too many partitions. With v12, you can probably go up to a few thousand, in earlier versions you will get performance problems earlier on.

Comment: Thanks. Also found this in the postgres docs:
```Note that partition pruning is driven only by the constraints defined implicitly by the partition keys, not by the presence of indexes. Therefore it isn't necessary to define indexes on the key columns. Whether an index needs to be created for a given partition depends on whether you expect that queries that scan the partition will generally scan a large part of the partition or just a small part. An index will be helpful in the latter case but not the former.``` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html